# ¿Cómo puedo devolver el agregado de una variable después de que finalice la ejecución del programa?

Tags: java, agregación

Tengo que hacer una pequeña aplicación en Java que valida si el usuario ganó, perdió y cuánto tiempo tomó en jugar.

Mi código me funciona bien al afichar cuántas partidas perdió o ganó el usuario ya que solamente asigna un +1 a la variable `ganado` o `perdido`.

Lo que me falta por hacer es que agregue a una variable `tiempoTotal` la cantidad de tiempo que se tomó el usuario.

Si la primera vez el usuario se tomó 10 minutos y la segunda vez 30 minutos, quisiera afichar en total 30 minutos.

Todavía no creo la variable ya que no sé cómo implementar la solución buscada.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto (el agregado del tiempo)?

Aquí está mi código:

```
Scanner Entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 

comenzarJuego = Entrada.nextInt();

while (comenzarJuego == 1)
{       
    System.out.println("Ha perdido o ganado?\n");
    System.out.println("Entre 1 por si gano el juego\n");
    System.out.println("Emntre 2 poor si perdio el juego\n");

    partida = Entrada.nextInt();

    if(partida == 1 )
    {
        ganado++;
    }
    else if (partida == 2 )
    {

        perdido++; 
    }


System.out.println("Quiere continuar a jugar? ente 1 para continuar y 2 para salir del programa.\n");

    comenzarJuego = Entrada.nextInt();

}
System.out.println("Numero de partidas perdidas: " + perdido);
System.out.println("numero de partidas ganadas : " + ganado);
System.out.println("Tiempo total del juego :" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que no esta usando ningun motor grafico, si lo esta usando puede mirar por algun metodo que devuelva el `deltaTime`, si no usa ningun motor grafico puede hacer uso de [`System.currentTimeMillis();`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) y un poco de matematicas:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Demo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   // rdevuelve el tiempo en milliseconds

   System.out.print("tiempo en milliseconds = ");
   System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());

  }
}
```

Algunos ejemplos:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
long end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Tiempo: " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms);
System.out.println("Tiempo: " + ((end - start) / 1000000000.0)) + "seg");
```

---

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Tiempo: " + ((end - start) / 1000)) + "seg");
```

Los ejemplos los puedes usar basicamente poniendo/capturando el inicio cuando entre el juego o lo que quieras calcular en `start` y cuando termina lo que quieras calcular lo almacenas en `end` luego haces la resta.

---

Con lo que le respondi no creo que tenga problemas en implementarlo en su codigo, no le pongo un ejemplo mas conciso porque no se muy bien lo que quiere hacer, o como y cuando quiere que se capture el tiempo, o si este debe de sumarse mientras no pierda, o se pare de sumar cuando el programa esta esperando que el usuario le diga 1 o 2, entre otras cosas sobre todo me desconcierta el `while` que le pregunta al jugardor si perdio o gano.

**Update** por comentario:

pseudocode:

```
    String time;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese el tiempo: ");

    time = scanner.nextLine();
```

Ahora podria usar `int tiempo = Integer.parseInt(time);` o por ejemplo [`Long.parseLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) o el que necesite.

Y realizar la operaciones matematicas que usted necesite.

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta. No estoy usando ningun motor grafico. Pero no busco mostrar el tiempor real del juego. Es el usuario quien va a entrar manualmente cuanto tiempo tomo, y cada vez que el continue en el while, le va a seguir preguntando cuando tiempo tomo hasta que ya salga del programa. lo que busco es sumar todas las veces que el entro el valor y aficharlo

Comment: @Aarancibia te deje alguno ejemplos y como usarlos, espero sea lo que buscas si tienes alguna duda comenta. Saludos

Comment: Al hacer lo que sugieres me resulta y me da el resultado total del juego. Pero no es lo que busco hacer. Lo que necesito hacer es que el usuario manualmente entre cuanto se demoro, luego que el entre cuanto se demoro en la segunda partida. y al final poder sumar si en la primera partida se demoro 10 minutos y en la segunda 20, que la suma me de 30 al final

Comment: @Aarancibia me imagino que sus motivos tendra, pero por que, esperar a que el usuario diga cuanto demoro cuando usted lo puede calcular por el, bueno de todas formas, si quieres que el usuario digite lo que tardo, una de varias o el usuario tiene acceso al tiempo que ha transcurrido, mirando su reloj cuando empieza y termina, mirando el del pc, o que usted se lo proporcione en la interface. Y para que ingrese el tiempo pues la misma logica mas o menos, usar el `Scanner` y `suVariableString = suScanner.nextLine();`. Saludos